# Why can't I scoop out some ID's of some strings using regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to scoop out some `ID`'s from some strings. The portion I would like to grab from each string is between `bd-` and `?`. The latter is not always present so I wish to make this sign ***?*** optional. I know I can achieve the same using string manipulation but I wish to do the same using regex.

I've tried with:

```
import re

content = """
id-HTRY098WE
id-KNGT371WE?witkl
id-ZXV555NQE?phnu
eh-VCBG075LK
"""
for item in re.findall(r'id-(.*)\??',content):
    print(item)
```

Output it yields:

```
HTRY098WE
KNGT371WE?witkl
ZXV555NQE?phnu
```

Expected output:

```
HTRY098WE
KNGT371WE
ZXV555NQE
```

***How can I scrape `ID`'s out of some strings?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a capturing group with a negated character class to match not a questionmark or a whitespace character.

The pattern that you tried first matches until the end of the string using `.*`. Then at the end of the string, it tries to match an optional question mark `\??`. This will succeed (because it is optional) resulting in matching the whole string for the first 3 examples.

```
id-([^?\s]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VOFg8L/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RGDFX9)

For example

```
import re

content = """
id-HTRY098WE
id-KNGT371WE?witkl
id-ZXV555NQE?phnu
eh-VCBG075LK
"""
for item in re.findall(r'id-([^?\s]+)',content):
    print(item)
```

Result

```
HTRY098WE
KNGT371WE
ZXV555NQE
```

Or match only alphanumerics:

```
id-([A-Z0-9]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VOFg8L/2)

Comment: Or possibly make the capturing group non-greedy and take anything up until `?` or the end of string, eg: `r'id-(.*?)[?\n]'` - then you're not having to worry about the criteria of what should possibly be contained in the id part...

Comment: @JonClements That would work indeed, but only if all the values end with a newline or a question mark.